# Why do AppBarButtons not respond to Tapped events in Windows Phone 8.1 RT Universal apps?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a pretty simple scenario in a Windows Phone 8.1 RT app.

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <AppBarButton Click="AppBarButton_Click" Tapped="AppBarButton_Tapped" Icon="Emoji"/>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

It's a brand new `Page`, no other code involved. On a real device and in the emulator the Tapped event is never called, but the Click event *is*.
I've tried using Commanding instead but not found it changed anything.

Anyone else come across this before? Any solutions?

Comment: Why do you need a tapped event as opposed to a click event? They are almost the same ain't it?

Comment: I've stumbled onto the same issue. The commands use to work on mine. I'm not sure what happened.

Answer (score 3):

If you have them both setup (Click Event & Tapped Event),
It will only focus on the Click Event, (if it's configured).

You can't just use them both like that. You'll have to mix the strings in the same Event.

I've tried this once and i found it useless to use them both.